# Cracks in the Universe & Language

Tags: doctor-who

First question here. In season 5 of the new series of Doctor Who, The Doctor encounters a series of "cracks in the universe", starting with one in seven-year-old Amelia Pond's bedroom wall. Through the crack, they hear voices: "Attention! Prisoner Zero has escaped."

Amelia has heard the voices before The Doctor arrives in the TARDIS. How could she understand what they were saying?

Comment: Well, if there are universal translators in the Whoniverse, you can assume that other environments than the TARDIS utilise them too. So the prison had them, probably.

Comment: ha! So simple. Of course! Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A tiny bit later into The Eleventh Hour, the Atraxi broadcast their message "Prisoner Zero will vacate the human residence, or the human residence will be incinerated." all over the world, in every possible language.

I think it is therefore safe to assume that the message little Amelia got to hear through the crack in her bedroom was in plain English, already. How the Atraxi can translate to the local language is not really explained, but Mr. Lister's comment on the original question might serve as an explanation for that.

Comment: You are right! Thank you. This is also more natural than the explanations I was considering.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I remember, she never states that she knows what was being said, she just says that she heard voices.

Comment: She does when the Doctor starts saying "Prisoner Zero has escaped." she finishes it.

Comment: @shachna I'll rewatch it, but when is that?

Comment: From 10'45" into the show to about 11'30".